# Migrate this function to RxJava

Tags: android, group-by, rx-java, criteria

In my project I'm using RxJava2 as I find it extremely powerful. Nevertheless, I'm stuck triying to figure out how could I migrate a method to RxJava2 syntax.

The app reads a XML file and emits an observable per node of the XML. Then I make some tasks over each emmited item and finally I group all operations in a list.

The problem is that some operations are 'repeated'. Let's see an example:

```
<CashTransaction dateTime="07/06/19;20:20:00" type="Withholding Tax" symbol="LNR" amount="-3.02" fxRateToBase="0.66496" />
<CashTransaction dateTime="07/06/19;20:20:00" type="Withholding Tax" symbol="LNR" amount="3.02" fxRateToBase="0.68529" />
<CashTransaction dateTime="07/06/19;20:20:00" type="Withholding Tax" symbol="LNR" amount="-3.02" fxRateToBase="0.68529" />
```

I have 3 different operations in the XML but I'd like to make a single one showing the equivalent of the 3 like this:

```
<CashTransaction dateTime="07/06/19;20:20:00" type="Withholding Tax" symbol="LNR" amount="-3.02" fxRateToBase="0.66496" />
```

At this moment I'm executing this method over the final list but I was wondering if I could do this inside the Observable Stream.

```
public static List<iIB> groupSplittedOperations(List<iIB> iIBNewTransactions)
{
    ArrayList<iIB> groupedOperations = new ArrayList<>();

    //Iterate all over the operations retrieved from the XML report
    for(int originalIndex = 0; originalIndex < iIBNewTransactions.size(); originalIndex++)
    {
        boolean exists = false;

        //This is current operation
        iIB currentOperation = iIBNewTransactions.get(originalIndex);

        //Check if current operation could be grouped into another operation iterating all 
        //over grouped operations
        for(int groupedIndex = 0; groupedIndex < groupedOperations.size(); groupedIndex++)
        {
            //This is current grouped operation
            iIB groupedOperation = groupedOperations.get(groupedIndex);

            //This is the criteria to determine if an operation could be grouped into another one
            if(currentOperation.getDateTime().equals(groupedOperation.getDateTime())
                && currentOperation.getOperationType().equals(groupedOperation.getOperationType())
                && currentOperation.getSymbol().equals(groupedOperation.getSymbol())
                && currentOperation.getDescription().equals(groupedOperation.getDescription()))
            {
                //Update amount of new operation and mark it as existent to avoid adding it to the grouped list
                groupedOperation.setAmount(String.valueOf(groupedOperation.getAmount() + currentOperation.getAmount()));
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //Only add operation to grouped list if it was not found on previous search
        if(!exists)
            groupedOperations.add(currentOperation);
    }

    return groupedOperations;
}
```

Comment: You can use `distinct` operator. You will have to provide how you differentiate your transaction for the operator to work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32291062/891373

Comment: I was also thinking of using `distinct()` - it would be most straightforward if you could override the `equals` method in your `iIB` class to only include the fields you want to use to check equality, so you can use it without needing to specify a key selector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe the example I showed is not the best. I think group by could fit better my needs because I'd like to make some operations to calculate final operation. What do you think?

Comment: It totally depends on your implementation and business logic. `groupBy` would actually group your results. You can also use `groupBy` as it would give different list of items and then you can select one/more element from that list and call `collect()` at the end of the stream.

Comment: I'd like to implement my own function for groupBy but I can't see any example. Every example I see uses groupBy with a single property.

Comment: Maybe you can create a hashcode of the elements that you want to groupBy with. Maybe _multiple_ groupBy could also work.

Comment: I think that's the right way. I'll try to implement this and post results in a few minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up with this piece of code which is working as expected. Thank you @Froyo for your guidelines.

```
//For each XML node, convert it to the appropriate object (cashTransaction or Trade)
//I'm not interested on CashTransactions of type 'Other_fees' with description containing 'CONSOLIDATED SNAPSHOTS'
Observable.just(XML.getObjectFromXMLNode(node)))
.filter(iIBTransaction -> !iIBTransaction.getDescription().contains(CashTransaction.OtherFees_filter))
.filter(iIBTransaction -> iIBTransaction.getTransactionID() != null)
.filter(iIBTransaction -> !iIBTransaction.getDateTime().equals("17/04/19"))

//As there might be some splitted or duplicated operations, I'd like to group them in a single one
.groupBy(iIB::getSymbol)
.flatMap(
 grp -> grp.groupBy(iIB::getDateTime)
     .flatMap(grp2 -> grp2.groupBy(iIB::getDescription))
         .flatMap(gpr3 -> gpr3.groupBy(iIB::getOperationType))
            .flatMapSingle(Observable::toList)
)

//The previous groupBy block emits List<iIB> that have the same datetime, description, operationType and symbol
.flatMap((Function<List<iIB>, ObservableSource<iIB>>) listiIB ->

    //For each List<iIB> group them in a single iIB
    listiIB.get(0).getTradePrice().equals(AppConstants.defaultEmptyFloat) ?
        Observable.just(CashTransaction.groupCashTransactions(listiIB)) :
        Observable.just(Trade.groupTrades(listiIB)))


//Then we check if current iiB is in Firebase (check its transactionID).
// If it is in Firebase, a new CashTransaction is returned (tradePrice == null).
// Otherwise, the original transaction is returned
.flatMap((Function<iIB, ObservableSource<iIB>>) iIB -> FirebaseClass.getInstance().checkIfNewOperation(iIB))
.filter(iIB -> iIB.getTradePrice() != null)

//We group all the emissions of previous observable in a single list to return all operations together
.toList());
```